# How to have deterministic prediction in reinforcement learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I have implemented basic trading model in RL and when i am trying to run every time it give different values of profit and Reward .While I am setting seed value
How we can make sure it give same value for same data whenever we try to run

Here is code

```
pip install stable-baselines3[extra]
```

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler,StandardScaler
```

```py
# for autoformatting
# %load_ext jupyter_black
```

```py
#!apt-get install ffmpeg freeglut3-dev xvfb  # For visualization
!pip install "stable-baselines3[extra]>=2.0.0a4" gym-anytrading gym
```

### Imports

Stable-Baselines3 works on environments that follow the [gym interface](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/custom_env.html).
You can find a list of available environment [here](https://gymnasium.farama.org/environments/classic_control/).

Not all algorithms can work with all action spaces, you can find more in this [recap table](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/algos.html)

```py
import gym
import gym_anytrading

# Stable baselines - rl stuff
from stable_baselines3 import A2C,PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv

# Processing libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

print(np.__version__)
```

```py
!pip install yfinance
```

The first thing you need to import is the RL model, check the documentation to know what you can use on which problem

```py
import yfinance as yf

ticker_symbol = "AAPL"  # Example: Apple Inc.

# Set the start and end dates for the data
start_date = "2010-01-01"
end_date = "2023-05-31"

# Retrieve the data using yfinance
yf_data = yf.download(ticker_symbol, start=start_date, end=end_date)
yf_data.index
# Convert the data to a Pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(yf_data)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df
```

```py
env = gym.make('stocks-v0', df=df, frame_bound=(10,len(df)-int(len(df)/2)), window_size=10)

seed_value = 42
env.seed(seed_value)

#env.signal_features
```

```py
!pip install finta

from gym_anytrading.envs import StocksEnv
from finta import TA
```

The next thing you need to import is the policy class that will be used to create the networks (for the policy/value functions).
This step is optional as you can directly use strings in the constructor:

`PPO('MlpPolicy', env)` instead of `PPO(MlpPolicy, env)`

Note that some algorithms like `SAC` have their own `MlpPolicy`, that's why using string for the policy is the recommended option.

```py
#df['SMA'] = TA.SMA(df, 12)
#df['RSI'] = TA.RSI(df)
#df['OBV'] = TA.OBV(df)
df['MACD'] = TA.MACD(df).MACD
df['SIGNAL'] = TA.MACD(df).SIGNAL
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

```py
TA.MACD(df)
```

```py
df.head(15)
```

```py
def add_signals(env):
    start = env.frame_bound[0] - env.window_size
    end = env.frame_bound[1]
    prices = env.df.loc[:, 'Close'].to_numpy()[start:end]
    sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
    #sc = StandardScaler()
    #signal_features = env.df.loc[:, ['Close', 'Volume','SMA', 'RSI', 'OBV','MACD','SIGNAL']].to_numpy()[start:end]
    signal_features = sc.fit_transform(env.df.loc[:, ['Volume','MACD','SIGNAL']])[start:end] #env.df.loc[:, ['Volume','MACD','SIGNAL']].to_numpy()[start:end]
    return prices, signal_features
```

```py
class MyCustomEnv(StocksEnv):
    _process_data = add_signals

env2 = MyCustomEnv(df=df, frame_bound=(10,len(df)-int(len(df)/2)), window_size=10)
```

```py
env_maker = lambda: env2
env = DummyVecEnv([env_maker])
```

```py
!pip install tensorrt
%load_ext tensorboard
```

```py
%tensorboard --logdir ./logs

import IPython

display(IPython.display.HTML('''
<button id='open_tb'>Open TensorBoard</button>
<button id='hide_tb'>Hide TensorBoard</button>
<script>document.querySelector('#open_tb').onclick = () => { window.open(document.querySelector('iframe').src, "__blank") }
        document.querySelector('#hide_tb').onclick = () => { document.querySelector('iframe').style.display = "none" }</script>'''))
```

```py
from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import EvalCallback, StopTrainingOnRewardThreshold
import os

save_path = os.path.join('Training', 'Saved Models')
stop_callback = StopTrainingOnRewardThreshold(reward_threshold=190, verbose=1)
eval_callback = EvalCallback(env,
                             callback_on_new_best=stop_callback,
                             eval_freq=10000,
                             best_model_save_path=save_path,
                             verbose=1)
```

```py
model = A2C('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=1,tensorboard_log="./logs")
model.learn(total_timesteps=100000,callback=eval_callback)
```

```py
env = MyCustomEnv(df=df, frame_bound=(int(len(df)/2)+10,len(df)), window_size=10)
seed_value = 42
env.seed(seed_value)
obs = env.reset()
while True:
    obs = obs[np.newaxis, ...]
    action, _states = model.predict(obs)
    obs, rewards, done, info = env.step(action)
    if done:
        print("info", info)
        break
```

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
plt.cla()
env.render_all()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `action, _states = model.predict(obs,deterministic=True)`